# changing array element property in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change value of an array element's property;

with a method such as:

```
incrementLike(productIm) {
    console.log(`incrementing ${productIm}`);
    const index = this.state.products.findIndex(o => o.Im === productIm);
    let selectedLikes = this.state.products[index].likes;
    this.setState({ selectedLikes: selectedLikes + 1 });
    console.log(`adding 1 to ${selectedLikes}`);
}
```

the array is defined as such:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        products: [
            {
                im: "corpo",
                likes: 1128
            },
            {
                im: "med",
                likes: 256
            },
            {
                im: "smart",
                likes: 512
            }
        ]
    };
```

How can I/should I do such thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you find the index, create a new array by spreading into it all the elements before the index, adding the modified object, and spreading all the objects after the index.

You also need to fix the `Im` typo, the property name is `im`. You also need to fix the `selectedLikes` property, the property name you're defining in the state is `likes`.

Live demo:

```js
class ProductList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [{
        im: "corpo",
        likes: 1128
      },
      {
        im: "med",
        likes: 256
      },
      {
        im: "smart",
        likes: 512
      }
    ]
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.products.map(({ im, likes }) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div onClick={() => this.incrementLike(im)}>{im}</div>
        <div>{likes}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
  }
  incrementLike(productIm) {
    const { products } = this.state;
    const index = products.findIndex(o => o.im === productIm);
    this.setState({
      products: [
        ...products.slice(0, index),
        { ...products[index], likes: products[index].likes + 1 },
        ...products.slice(index + 1),
      ]
    });
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<ProductList />, document.querySelector('#react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: But: TypeError: products[index] is undefined

Comment: You have a typo, make sure the property defined in the state is the same one you're using in the method - capitalization matters

Comment: You also need to fix the `likes` property typo - either use `likes` or `selectedLikes`, but not both

Answer (score 0):

I find the use of filter quite handy to be honest. I would try something like:

```
const index = this.state.products.filter(o => o.Im.includes(productIm));
/* code to set the value here */
```

Good luck!